# how to extract filename in this situation?

Tags: regex, perl, text-extraction

my input strings look like this:

```
1    warning: rg: W, MULT: file 'filename_a.h' was listed twice.
2    warning: rg: W, SCOP: scope redefined in '/proj/test/site_a/filename_b.c'.
3    warning: rg: W, ATTC: file /proj/test/site_b/filename_c.v is not resolved.
4    warning: rg: W, MULTH: property file filename_d.vu was listed outside.
```

They come in four different flavors as listed above. I read these from a log file line by line.

For the one with path specified (line 2,3) I can extract filename using `$file=~s#.*/##;` and seems to work fine. Is there a way not to use conditional statements for different type and extract the filename? I want to use just one clean regex and extract the filename. Perl's `File::basename` will not work also in this case.

I am using Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in two steps:

- extract path from each line
- get basename from the path

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/C7evl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
use feature 'say';
use File::Basename;

#NOTE: assume that unquoted path has no spaces in it 
say basename($1.$2) if /(?:file|redefined in)\s+(?:'([^']+)'|(\S+))/;
```

#### Output

```
filename_a.h
filename_b.c
filename_c.v
filename_d.vu
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem needs more constraints.  For example, what's a good way to characterize a string as a "path" (or "filename") or not?  You might say, "Hey, when I see a single dot immediately followed by letters and numbers (but not symbols), and there are a bunch of characters before that dot too, then it might be a path or filename!"

```
\s+([^\s]+\.\w+)
```

But this doesn't catch all paths, nor files without an extension.  So we might latch on an alternation to say, "Either the above, or, a string with at least one slash in it."

```
\s+([^\s]+\.\w+|[^\s]*\/[^\s]*)
```

(Note that you may not need to escape the slash in the above example, since you seem to be using `#` as your delimiter.)

What I'm getting at, in any case, is that you need to specify your problem more rigorously, and this will automatically bring you to a satisfying solution.  Of course, there is no truly "correct" solution using regexes alone: you'd need to do file tests to do that.

To go further with this example, perhaps you want to define a list of extensions:

```
\s+([^\s]+\.(?:c|h|cc|cpp)|[^\s]*\/[^\s]*)
```

Or, perhaps you want to be more generic, but allow only extensions up to 4 characters long:

```
\s+([^\s]+\.\w{1,4}|[^\s]*\/[^\s]*)
```

Perhaps you only consider something a path if it begins with a slash, but you still want at least one another slash somewhere in it:

```
\s+([^\s]+\.\w{1,4}|/[^\s]*\/[^\s]*)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

/\w*.\w*/
This will match the file name expressed in the four different warning logs. \w will match any word character (letters, digits, and underscores), so this regex looks for any number of word characters, followed by a dot followed by more word characters.
This works because the only other dot in your logs is at the end of the log.

Comment: Change the stars to pluses, since this would currently match lone dots, as well as "twice.", "resolved.", etc.